# Tupling floats into pairs and adding them to a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file of countries and some describing coordinates, with the following format:

> *Country*
>
> 57.7934235704;24.3128625831 58.3834133979;24.42892785 58.2573745795;24.0611983579 58.6127534044;23.4265600929

And i'm having trouble converting the file into a python dictionary with `country` as the key, and the values as list of lists of float-tuples, like so:

`[[(57.7934235704, 24.3128625831), (58.3834133979, 24.42892785), (58.2573745795, 24.0611983579), (58.6127534044, 23.4265600929)]]`

I've managed to end up with the following code, which in my understanding manages to add the country as a key, and floats the coordinates individually, so what's missing is a way to tuple the floats in pairs, and add them to their corresponding country.

```
def read_country_file(filename):
with open(filename) as file:
    dict = {}
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip().split(' ')
        for element in line:
            if re.match('^[A-Z]', element):  #if the line starts with a letter make it a key
                country = (element[0:])
                dict[country] = country
            elif re.match('^[-0-9;. ]', element):  #if the line starts with a number make it a value
                element = element.split(';')
                for i in element:
                    flo = float(i)
                #MISSING: Tuple floats in pairs and add them to the dictionary
return dict
```

If I lookup a country in this dictionary, it will find the country/key correctly, but it has no values attached. And if I type-test my "flo" value it's a float, so i have a feeling I'm almost there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use tuple comprehension:

```
element =  tuple(float(i) for i in element.split(';'))
```

Additionally, my solution for your problem:

```
import re

text = ['Vietnam',
        '57.7934235704;24.3128625831 58.3834133979;24.42892785 58.2573745795;24.0611983579 58.6127534044;23.4265600929']

def get_tuples_of_float(string):
    return [tuple(map(float, j)) for j in re.findall('([\d.]+);([\d.]+)', string)] 

it = iter(text)
output = { i : get_tuples_of_float(next(it)) for i in it if re.match('^[A-Z]', i)}
```

Comment: Sometimes getting everything into a one line expression isn't a good thing. Sure this might work but it takes longer than it needs to to understand what it's doing.

Comment: `element =  tuple(float(i) for i in element.split(';'))`


Works perfectly, but how do i add them into the dictionary correctly afterwards?

Comment: @JohnAnderson: With your source code, you need to save the key in a temporary var, then use it to add.

Comment: @JohnAnderson: Or you can try my solution by replacing `text` by `file`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = """
57.7934235704;24.3128625831 58.3834133979;24.42892785 58.2573745795;24.0611983579 58.6127534044;23.4265600929
"""
new_data = map(float, re.findall('[\d\.]+', s))
final_data = {new_data[i]:new_data[i+1] for i in range(0, len(new_data), 2)}
```

Output:

```
{58.6127534044: 23.4265600929, 58.2573745795: 24.0611983579, 58.3834133979: 24.42892785, 57.7934235704: 24.3128625831}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you first split each line of text based on spaces and then the array that comes out from it, you then split each individual coordinate pair based on the semicolons that are common to them then you can now add everything to the country key on the dictionary.